# Align math with the items of an enumerate environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I have some math in an enumerate environment but as you can see in the picture the equations are below the numbers and not aligned horizontally. Why is that and how can I align them?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item 
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{m=0}^{n}a = (n+1)\cdot a
\end{equation*}

\item 
\begin{align*}
    & \delta(n)\ast \delta{n} = \delta(n)\\
    & \delta(n) \ast x(n)=x(n)
\end{align*}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `$\begin{aligned}[t] ... \end{aligned}$` instead of `equation` or `align`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thank you.  I don't believe I missed that question!

Comment: No problem. Search here can sometimes be difficult. I had difficulty finding it, even though I knew that I had provided an answer. Plus having a duplicate question may help others in the future find it, so your question is still useful.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes I search a lot and I try to use a good title so I can be provided by the system with possible similar questions but you can't know how the other person phrased his post's title. Your response was very quick though. :)